# Check if a time range is not within other time ranges?

Tags: javascript

I need to check if the given time range is available or not.

**Array with busy hours:**

```
[
  { from: 2, to: 4 },
  { from: 8, to: 10 }
]
```

**The compartment I want to check**

```
{ from: 3, to: 6 }
```

**Expected result:**

```
{ from: 1, to: 2 } // true
{ from: 5, to: 7 } // true
{ from: 3, to: 4 } // false
{ from: 9, to: 10 } // false
```

Comment: I imagine you could start with a `for` loop of some kind. What have you tried? Please show your best attempt and explain what went wrong (errors, unexpected results, etc.)

Comment: What exactly do you want to find out ? whether it lies in any one range from 1st array ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const arr = [
  { from: 2, to: 4 },
  { from: 8, to: 10 }
]

function checkTime(arr,obj){
  return !arr.some(x => x.from <= obj.from && x.to >= obj.to);
}

let tests = [
  { from: 1, to: 2 },
  { from: 5, to: 7 }, 
  { from: 3, to: 4 },
  { from: 9, to: 10 }
]
tests.forEach(x => console.log(checkTime(arr,x)));
```

Comment: I am sorry, I should add some examples to the question. Thank you for recommending Array.some() function, now I have to remember previous results ;)

Comment: @Adee You might explain the question a little more please what is role of `{ from: 3, to: 6 }`. Explain why particular input returns true or false.

Comment: I assume that the day is 24 hours (from 0 - 23). I need to check if the given time range is free (there are no other reservations at this time).

Comment: It is much better, but some options still disagree {from: 1, to: 3}, {from: 5, to: 10}... 
What do you think about changing the compartments into array elements? Example {from: 2, to: 5} => [2,3,4,5] or without borders [3,4]?